# Passing data from mutable array in data store to a UILabel in the View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am new to iOS Programming, and programming as a whole, and I have an issue with a project I am currently working on. I am working on a quiz application where I would like to store my questions in an object containing the array of questions. My quiz ViewController then imports the question bank and displays those questions in a `UILabel` in the View.

Sorry if this is somewhat of a noob issue but I can't seem to figure it out and web searches have not helped much either. I am still quite early in the learning process.

I have:
    ViewController.h
    ViewController.m
    QuestionBank.h
    QuestionBank.m

In QuestionBank.h:

```
//QuestionBank.h

#import <Foundation.h>

@interface QuestionBank : NSObject

- (id)initWithQuestionsArray:(NSMutableArray *)questions;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *questions;
@property in currentQuestionIndex;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *currentQuestion;
@end
```

In QuestionBank.m:

```
//QuestionBank.m

#import "QuestionBank.h"

@implementation QuestionBank;
@synthesize questions _questions;
@synthesize currentQuestionIndex;
@synthesizeCurrentQuestion;

- (id)initWithQuestionsArray:(NSMutableArray *)questions
   {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_quesitons addObject:@"What is the 14 +6?];
    [_questions addObject:@"What is my name?"];
    [_questions addObject:@"What is my age?"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCurrentQuestion:(NSString *)q
{
    q = [_questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex];
}
```

In ViewController.h

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit>
@class QuestionBank;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationController Delegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *questionLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) QuestionBank *questionBank;
```

In ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "QuestionBank.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize questionLabel;
@synthesize questionBank;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = _subjectName;

    if (self.title == @"AGK") {
    [_questionLabel setText:self.questionBank.currentQuestion];
    NSLog(@"AGK was selected");
    }
}
```

With the code I have the question I have in the array does not appear in the `UILabel` (The label is properly hooked up to the `ViewController`).

Please feel free to point out any errors, share any suggestions for how I could get this to work, and any general improvements I can make anywhere else in my code.

Comment: If you're just starting out with iOS programming, I suggest going on iTunes U and getting the course on iPhone/iPad programming from Stanford University, I believe the instructor's name is Paul Hegarty. It's completely free and very informative.

Comment: @MrOBrian Thanks for the suggestion but I already signed up for the Coding Together course that took place over the summer, which is based on P.H.'s lectures, but I fell way behind because I had some exams to study for and sit. I am also working my way through the Big Nerd Ranch book on iOS Programming.

Comment: where are you initializing self.questionBank?

Comment: The great thing about iTunes U is you can download the lectures and watch them at your own pace. XCode is pretty good about finding errors in your code, and if the code you posted is your actual code then XCode must be complaining when you try to build.

Comment: @jere I guess my reply to your question is where should I, and how should I initialize self.questionBank? The methods I have tried have resulted in crashes. I would like to initialize it in the viewDidLoad method, within the if statement, so the app eventually functions such that  a particular questionBank is loaded corresponding to the subject that is selected by the user.

Comment: @MrOBrian Certainly. I have completed the first two assignments, and plan to finish everything. I'm doing my own stuff on the side to make sure what I learn is actually sticking in there.

Comment: hey lybron please listen to MrOBrain as he is suggesting you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has quite a few issues and needs a number of fixes.  Here are a few of them:

I don't think you fully understand how passing variables to functions works in Objective C.  For example, in your - (void)setCurrentQuestion:(NSString *)q method, you aren't really DOING anything.  For example, allow me to demonstrate the following code in a pretend program:

```
- (void)testStringPassing:(NSString *)string
{
    string = @"Goodbye World!";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *string = @"Hello World.";
    [self testStringPassing:string];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

In that example code, you are going to log "Hello World", NOT "Goodbye World".  So, essentially, -(void)testStringPassing:(NSString *)string isn't really doing anything.  If you wanted to change the value of "string", you would want to do something more like this:

```
- (NSString *)testStringPassing
{
    return @"Goodbye World";
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *string = @"Hello World";
    string = [self testStringPassing];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

That code will log "Goodbye World" because you return a value for testStringPassing and set "string" to be equal to that value.

Again, this pertains to your code because your -(void)setCurrentQuestion(NSString*)q method is like the first example where you don't really accomplish anything.

You have to allocate and initialize your classes before you use them.  In your ViewController, you attempt to use your questionBank class before allocating and initializing it.  Try something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]
    self.questionBank = [[QuestionBank alloc] init];

    //the rest of your code here
}
```

A combination of the above two problems is that you are using - (id)initWithQuestionsArray:(NSMutableArray *)questions as a custom initializer, but you are not using the passed value for anything.  In your current code, I would suggest replacing your  -(id)initWithQuestionsArray:(NSMutableArray *)questions code with the following code:

```
- (id)init
{
    self.questions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.questions addObject:@"Your Question Text Goes Here!!!!"];
    [self.questions addObject:@"Another question can go here."];
}
```

The underscore naming convention is sort of frowned upon in Objective C because it defeats the point of having properties synthesized and using the generated getters and setters.  Especially since you are just learning, I would abandon underscore notation.  Replace

```
@synthesize questions _questions;
```

with

```
@synthesize questions;
```

Then, anywhere you access your questions array, use self.questions instead of _questions.

Anyway, that should be enough to get you started/pointed in the right direction.  I highly suggest picking up a book that focuses on JUST Objective C.  Learning iOS is great, but so many resources assume you already know or are familiar with Objective C, but it seems that this is not the case.

Comment: Your recommendations worked. Thank you so much for your patience and for your help. I have been reading but sometimes it doesn't gel together until you try it all on your own and get feedback from actual people. Clearly there are a few things I misunderstood; I will take your advice and go over it again. Thank you.